# Using generated columns to cast existing column to float in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, types

Why doesn't this work in SQLite3? I'm trying to generate a column from an existing column by casting it into a new type.

```
drop table if exists projects;

create table projects("registered_budget" text, "registered_budget_f" as (cast("registered_budget") as float));

insert into projects ("registered_budget") values (NULL);
insert into projects ("registered_budget") values ("50,000");
insert into projects ("registered_budget") values ("5,000");

select sum(registered_budget) from projects;
```

Instead what I get is a big error:

```
sqlite> .read test_float.sql
Error: near line 3: near ")": syntax error
Error: near line 5: no such table: projects
Error: near line 7: near ";": syntax error
Error: near line 9: no such table: projects
Error: near line 13: no such table: projects
```

Why does this occur and what is a viable alternative?

Comment: You have several missing closing parentheses, e.g. in the `create table` statement and the second `insert` statement.

Comment: I fixed those and still get the same error...

Comment: Why is this question closed? What could possibly be wrong with it?

Comment: it's not closed because there's something "wrong" with it, but because it's not super useful to the community at large to keep this question around forever. Questions that were caused by a simple typo (like a wrongly placed parenthesis) are not considered on-topic (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). No hard feelings about it of course! Though, next time feel free to look a little more carefully at the query documentation before you post. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for the `CAST` operator is wrong. Instead of `cast(registered_budget) as float` it needs to be:

```
cast(registered_budget as float)
```